# Create multiple instances of object from one form in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a case where I want a very simple "webshop".
A sale consists of one or many items.

```
class Sale(models.Model):
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
  value = models.FloatField()


class Item(models.Model):
  seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller)

  value = models.FloatField()
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

  sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale)
```

What I am struggling with is to create a form that creates a Sale that in turn contains multiple Items. I have conceptually a simple page setup that has a basic "shopping cart" where the user can add multiple items.

But I dont know how to get the data in a good format back to the django app to interpret, validate, create the instances etc.

I am starting to think about a solution where I jus send back a JSON-snippet containing the cart via Javascript and let django app interpret that bit of information... but I would rather be able to use the django forms.

Any guidelines, ideas, solutions?

Comment: How about `inlineformset_factory`? it fits all your needs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668351/django-multiple-forms-with-formsets/26669428#26669428

Answer (score 3):

Ran into your problem just now. Maybe you have found a solution since it's been 5 years already. But if not, you can use formset factory for the model `Item` and the usual model form for the model `Sale`. This helps you create multiple instances of Item by rendering n number times your Item model in a form.

You can check this link https://medium.com/all-about-django/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0. It provides good example of how to use formset factory.