# Uploading image in template

Tags: django

I created two models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
    image = models.ImageField('New photos', upload_to='img/newphotos', blank=True)
```

I want add new cities through template so i created:

views.py

```
def newcity(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CityForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            city = form.save(commit=False)
            city.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return redirect('city.views.detailcity', pk=city.pk)
    else:
        form = CityForm()
    return render(request, 'city/editcity.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
class CityForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('name', 'country', 'image',)
```

Everything is ok but when I add image there is nothing happens - image is chosen but when I click save button new city is added without image (in admin panel it works). What must I add to my code? And how can i make possibility to add to one city few images? When i will add first image there should appear button to add second etc. Now I have place only for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `request.FILES` in your views

```
form = CityForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

and make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `method="post"` in your template

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES

Comment: thanks :) maybe you know how can I add few images to one city?

Comment: yes, but it is another question :D ... declare CityImage(models.Model) and add two fields to it:  your image and city = models.ForeignKey('City') ... now you will have relation - many city images to one city ... in your views use formsets (here is how I do usually http://stackoverflow.com/a/26669428/3033586 ) good luck! =)