# Django Python Forms - submitting complex view with multiple forms and formsets

Tags: django, python-3.x, ajax, django-forms, ajaxform

Imagine this concept,
I have a Taxi that can be ordered by a group for a full day multiple visits, and I should assign a group leader for each booking.
now I have a Booking (**PNR**) that holds **Clients** traveling Routes, and a Group Leader (**Operator**) assigned for that booking.

my view holds these:

1. form for selecting the *operator*
2. formset to add *clients*

in this view I'm trying to make it easier for the user by giving the ability to save each form separately by `ajax` or save all data of forms by a button at the bottom of the view.

I've been searching for a few days and I got the nearest approach on these two linkes [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668351/django-multiple-forms-with-formsets) & [2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) but still can't make my code run correctly and do what it's supposed to do. :( ANY SUPPORT WILL BE HIGHLY APPRECIATED!

My **models.py**:

```
class Operator (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # Other Fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code


class PNR (models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # Other Fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk


class Client (models.Model):
    related_pnr = models.ForeignKey(PNR, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # Other Fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.related_pnr+" "+self.name
```

My **forms.py**:

```
class ChooseOperatorCode(forms.Form):
    operator = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Operator.objects.all())

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        operator = self.cleaned_data.get('operator')

        return super(ChooseOperatorCode, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)


class NewClientForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={}), label=False, max_length=200)
    # Other Fields

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        # Other Fields

        return super(NewClientForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

My **views.py**:

```
@login_required
def create_pnr(request):

    pnr = PNR.objects.create(created_by_user=request.user)

    choose_operator_form = ChooseOperatorCode(request.POST or None)
    if choose_operator_form.is_valid():
        pnr.created_by_operator = choose_operator_form.cleaned_data.get('operator')
        pnr.save()
        choose_operator_form.save()

    clients_form = NewClientForm(request.POST or None)
    if clients_form.is_valid():
        client = Client()
        client.related_pnr = pnr.pk
        client.name = clients_form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        client.save()
        clients_form.save()
    context = {
        'pnr': pnr.pk,
        'choose_operator_form': choose_operator_form,
        'clients_form': clients_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'reservation_new.html', context)


@login_required
def edit_pnr(request, pnr_id):
    pnr = PNR.objects.get(id=pnr_id) 

    choose_operator_form = ChooseOperatorCode(request.POST or None)
    if choose_operator_form.is_valid():
        pnr.created_by_operator = choose_operator_form.cleaned_data.get('operator')
        pnr.save()

    clients_form = NewClientForm(request.POST or None)
    if clients_form.is_valid():
        client = Client()
        client.related_pnr = pnr.pk
        client.name = clients_form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        client.save()
        clients_form.save()
    context = {
        'pnr': pnr.pk,
        'choose_operator_form': choose_operator_form,
        'clients_form': clients_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'reservation_edit.html', context)
```

My **url.py**:

```
    path('operation/reservation/new/', views.create_pnr, name='new_pnr'),
    path('operation/reservation/existing/<int:pnr_id>/', views.edit_pnr, 
       name='existing_pnr'),
```

And Finally my **template.html**: (for both *new* and *edit*)

```
<form  method="POST" action="{% url 'existing_pnr' pnr_id=pnr %}" id="choose_operator_form">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{choose_operator_form}}
</form>
<form  method="POST" action="{% url 'existing_pnr' pnr_id=pnr %}" id="clients_form">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{clients_form}}
</form>
<script type="javascript">
    $(document).('submit', '#choose_operator_form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"{% url 'existing_pnr' %}",
            data: $('#choose_operator_form').serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                // show success msg
            },
            error: function (data) {
                // show error msg
            }
        });
    });

    //same code for clients form
</script>
```

Comment: What's the problem? What isn't working? Are you getting errors? Is some part of your code not doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: two things I wanna know, can I actually apply this concept *give user ability to save each form separately with ajax and ability to submit all forms and formsets at once?* and how to apply this approach?

the second thing  that it giving me errors that when I hit save for ```choose_Operator_form``` says ```'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'pnr'```

Comment: yes, conceptually you can do that, as long as you remove the form after it was successfully submitted via ajax, so that it doesn't get submitted twice if the user then clicks "submit all".

Comment: and second, why would you expect `request.pnr` to work? How can Django add a `pnr` to the `request` object?

Comment: I've tried adding extra hidden input within the form but still same issue

Comment: what issue do you mean by same issue?

Comment: ```'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'pnr'```

Comment: But I told you, why would you expect `request.pnr` to work? Where is `pnr` coming from? Django has no idea of `pnr`. Normally, in an edit view, you have the id of the object to edit in the url, define a variable in the `path` (urls.py) and pass it to your view that would be `def edit_pnr(request, pnr_id): ...`.

Comment: can you make answer to show how to pass the pnr to url in form action? because I tired to add variable to url.py like ```../<int:pnr>/``` it raise error, and if I removed it it raises error too ```Reverse for 'existing_pnr' with keyword arguments '{'pnr_id': 94}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['operation\\/reservation\\/existing\\/$']```

Comment: Looks like you're using `pnr_id` instead of `pnr`. Make sure the url pattern, view and `reverse` lookup use the same variable name.

Comment: yea I changed it, but it's not the error I'm aware of this point .. I've changed it everywhere

Comment: `{% url 'existing_pnr' pnr_id=pnr %}` and `path('../<int:pnr_id>/', ...)`

Comment: Yea I tried this but not working :( It's driving me crazy for 3 days

Comment: Show us your edited code, edit the question (add an edit at the bottom with all the new code and the new error you get, like this: "Edit: I now tried this: .... and it now gives me this error: ....).

Comment: dude You are so supportive, you are appreciated! I just removed the ajax code every thing working now ! you can type your answer now and I'll Up vote it, you deserve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pnr` doesn't get added to the `request` object, so `request.pnr` makes no sense. You need to pass the `id` of the `PNR` through the URL, that way it can be accessed in the view:

- In urls.py, make sure that the url for your `edit_pnr` view gets the `pnr_id`: something like `path('pnr/<int:pnr_id>/edit/', ..., name="existing_pnr")`.
- In your template, construct the url for editing a pnr like this: `{% url 'existing_pnr' pnr_id=pnr %}`
- In your view, receive the `pnr_id`: `def edit_pnr(request, pnr_id): ...`

Now you can fetch the `PNR` that's being edit like this: `pnr = get_object_or_404(PNR, pk=pnr_id)` which will correctly return a 404 Not Found if someone tries to access a non-existing `PNR`.